# How to keep banner animations running while changing webpages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

To start off, here's a picture of the website project:
http://i.imgur.com/FbdUmpp.png 

The top image is one of the cycling images in the website banner. I'd like to make my website a bit more polished. When the user navigates to a new webpage, the banner animation will restart. I was wondering how I could stop this from happening.

- How can I keep the banner from restarting when a user switches a
  webpage?
- What's the exact name of what I'm trying to accomplish? (I can't seem to find any information about this subject.)
- My knowledge is limited to HTML, CSS, a little bit of PHP and JavaScript. I don't mind learning a new language in order to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: This isn't probably the most ideal way of doing this, but I can see this being possible by creating a `frame` in html. The frame is basically gonna be a separate html page that doesn't change, and the actual navigational part of the site is gonna be another frame. It'll give off the illusion of it being one page, but two separate pages in reality. Just make sure to set the `frameborder` attribute to `0`.  A alternative to do this maybe AJAX

Comment: or use iframe.. but if you do.. google will hate you!

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard : I am aware that it is a bit of a broad question. However I am not really looking for a detailled explanation. If someone could push me in the right direction, I'd be very happy.

@ izuhu @ Jean-philippe Edmond : Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the animation restart is due to the content being reloaded when you land on the new page. There is no way around that specifically. However you can change the content on the screen without actually navigating away. Look into AJAX to accomplish this. Have an AJAX call get the new data that you want to view and place it on the current screen in place of the old data. This way you will still get the new information and the animation of the banner will continue without stops or restarting.